# Why I can run "artisan migrate" from host in Ubuntu but not in Windows

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

**The issue**
I have installed docker in **Ubuntu 16.04** and **Windows 10 pro**. I use docker-compose and Laravel framework, the weird thing is that I can run “php artisan migrate” in Ubuntu without problems with the same docker-compose.yml, but in Windows return message “not found driver pdo”. I do all this from host, not container. Into container I have not got trouble.

**The request**
I wonder why happens this issue in Windows because is the same "docker-compose.yml" file in both, may be some body could help me.

I paste the yml file

Thanks

```
version: '2'
services:
  # **docker-compose.yml**

  # The Application
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www

    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

  # The Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  # The Database
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=motordb"
      - "MYSQL_USER=pedro"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"
  # The PhpMyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - database:mysql
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    environment:
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: secret
      PMA_HOST: mysql

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Here Laravel evinronment file ".env"

```
APP_NAME=Motor
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:0S0uQqTfYj02dsednm0S5iAPyNuF8uxWF50nX4opUKI=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33061
DB_DATABASE=motordb
DB_USERNAME=pedro
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Comment: Please put Dockerfile as well, looks like you have not enabled PDO driver in your PHP's config, or it not installed at all (for windows)

Comment: What? then why it works when I enter into container in Windows and why it works in Linux Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I know, because in Ubuntu there is a php local with the same configuration than the server container php. Now I changed the php.ini in Windows 10 pro, and it works, the proof.

[image: Running migrations in docker container from windows host]